# A geometric interpretation of why the principal axis of a conic section is along the Eigenvectors?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, conic-sections

*Algebraicall*y, I understand we need to find the normalized eigenvectors to orthogonally diagonalize the matrix to remove the "xy" term. *Geometricall*y, I see that the eigenvectors represent the direction of the conic section's principal axis, therefore finding them we can "rotate" the axis to solve the question. But I can't grasp why the eigenvector is in the direction of the principal axis. Is it just because the eigenvectors in this context are orthogonal? But that still feels "lucky" that they happened to align themselves with the conic section perfectly.

Comment: Please add more details. What is the "xy" term? What conic section? Do you mean the characteristic polynomial? I'm confused.

Comment: Hi, I am referring to a general conic section and converting it using the quadratic form. Hope it helps!

Comment: Ok then. Sorry but I don't know how to answer your question. Best of luck!

Comment: No worries, thanks anyways!

Comment: The eigenvectors give you a basis in which the conic section looks like a "standard" conic section, so since the principal axes of "standard" conic sections are along the standard basis, the transformed principal axes will be along the transformed basis. In particular, in this basis, the equation looks like a weighted sum of squares. Look at the formal statement here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_axis_theorem

Comment: @OsamaGhani I see what you mean... It is as if the eigenvectors allow us to rotate the conic into a standard form. But geometrically, what is the property of eigenvectors that make them capable of doing this? It seems arbitrary why they happen to be in the principal axes.

Comment: It's not the property of the eigenvectors necessarily, but rather the property of an eigenvalue decomposition. When you diagonalize $A = PDP^{-1}$, the eigenvectors give you a basis in which $A$ looks simple (looks like stretching/reflection along each eigenvector, according to the associated eigenvalue). So doing a decomposition here gives you a basis in which the transformation just looks like stretching/reflection (and yes rotation).

Comment: Let me know if this rationale is correct: using eigenvalue decomposition allows us to find the "representation" of the conic section in the simplest form, ie: along the standard basis with no shearing. (Because the matrix is diagonalized, right?). And by virtue of you employing eigenvalue decomposition, the eigenvectors will be its basis, ie: the principal axis.

Comment: Consider a positive-definite quadratic form, which corresponds geometrically with an ellipsoid. It’s not too hard to show that the local extrema of this quadratic form on the unit (hyper)sphere are precisely in the directions of its eigenvectors, which also correspond to the principal axes of the ellipsoid.